# Configuring iptables for incoming static NAT

Tags: iptables, nat

I got a router with ssh access to it, iptables are there waiting for me. I am trying to map any connection to port 1337 on both WAN/LAN to my computer's port 1337. How do I do that?

Comment: Don't you have a web management interface for that ?

Comment: I do, but it's not working.

Comment: Maybe a firmware upgrade is in place.

Comment: Nah, I think this is intended behavior in some way. I've read some forum threads with developer comments in them. This guy thinks that users should do some work on their own, including (at some point) something like configuring iptables manually and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1337 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:1337
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 1337 -j ACCEPT
```

Where :

- eth0 need to be the WAN interface.
- 192.168.1.2 is your local LAN computer.

*I would still recommend using the WEBUI to manage the iptables rules.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Will this be still working after a reboot of the router? I got no iptables-save.
In web interface port forwarding isn't working.

Comment: I don't think so, there should be a init system for the device, initv or something like that, which can be plugged to load the content of the file you create with `iptable-save`.